# How to use MongoDB.AspNet.Identity with WebApi2

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am building a WebApi2 project and wanted to use mongodb as a backend and I found [MongoDB.AspNet.Identity package](https://github.com/InspectorIT/MongoDB.AspNet.Identity), I used it before in MVC5 website and it worked well, but after installing in the WebApi project I got an error: 
[image]

*Error  1   The type or namespace name 'IdentityUserLogin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \Controllers\AccountController.cs*

How to fix that? or it is impossible to use [MongoDB.AspNet.Identity package](https://github.com/InspectorIT/MongoDB.AspNet.Identity) with WebApi2 projects?

Answer (score 7):

Change every occurence of `IdentityUserLogin` to `UserLoginInfo`. Furthermore change

```
user.Logins.Add(new UserLoginInfo
        {
            LoginProvider = externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            ProviderKey = externalLogin.ProviderKey
        });
```

to

```
user.Logins.Add(new UserLoginInfo(
            externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            externalLogin.ProviderKey
        ));
```

Should work now.

Answer (score 2):

You mean replace,

```
user.Logins.Add(new IdentityUserLogin 
{
  LoginProvider = externalLogin.LoginProvider,
  ProviderKey = externalLogin.ProviderKey
});
```

to

```
user.Logins.Add(new UserLoginInfo(
        externalLogin.LoginProvider,
        externalLogin.ProviderKey
));
```